# What kind of simple datastore should I use in my android application?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying out a little android programming and I'm thinking about to do a simple tasklist application. What is better to use? Plain textfiles or xml? And if I choose xml as a datastore, what is the API for using xml in java? What is preferred?

Comment: There is something called SQLite database which comes with android. That would be best option.

Answer (score 0):

For basic info you can also store items in a key value pairs in the shared preferences

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html